# How to get some characters in String Android

Tags: java, android, string

I have a dynamic String like "Longitude (141.35642453456) Latitude (532.892392)", longitude and latitude can change when the location is different.

My question is How to get longitude number and set it to String longitude? and How to get latitude number and set it to String latitude?

Comment: will you get "Longitude (141.35642453456) Latitude (532.892392)" as a response? or only number as a response?

Comment: only number longitude set to String longitude, and only number latitude set to String latitude @Swapnil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one easy solution:

```
    class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Longitude (141.35642453456) Latitude (532.892392)";

        String s = input.replaceAll("[^0-9.\\s]", "");
        //  141.35642453456  532.892392
        System.out.println(s);

        String trim = s.trim();
        System.out.println(trim);

        String[] split = trim.split("\\s+");

        String longitude = split[0];
        String latitude = split[1];

        System.out.println(longitude);
        System.out.println(latitude);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For static use, You can simply get the substring using:-

```
    String lonlat = "Longitude (141.35642453456) Latitude (532.892392)";
    String longitude = lonlat.substring(lonlat.indexOf("(") + 1, lonlat.indexOf(")"));
    String latitude = lonlat.substring(lonlat.lastIndexOf("(") + 1, lonlat.lastIndexOf(")"));
```

Or you can do it more dynamically for more values

```
    String example = "Longitude (141.35642453456) Latitude (532.892392)";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\(([^)]+)\\)").matcher(example);
    ArrayList<String> latLonng = new ArrayList<>();
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        latLonng.add(m.group(1));
    }
    String longitude = latLonng.get(0);
    String latitude = latLonng.get(1);
```